# I want to place row at the bottom of the screen wrapping it with expanded widget is not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to place this row at the bottom of the screen

```dart
 Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    SizedBox(
      width: 40,
    ),
    CircleAvatar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      radius: 27,
      child: Icon(Icons.add_call),
    ),
    SizedBox(
      width: 40,
    ),
    CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        radius: 27,
        child: Icon(Icons.mail)),
    SizedBox(
      width: 40,
    ),
    CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        radius: 27,
        child: Icon(Icons.credit_card)),
  ],
),
```

Comment: i have post an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`bottomNavigationBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html) of `Scaffold`.

```dart
 return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: 40,
          ),
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            radius: 27,
            child: Icon(Icons.add_call),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 40,
          ),
          CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              radius: 27,
              child: Icon(Icons.mail)),
          SizedBox(
            width: 40,
          ),
          CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              radius: 27,
              child: Icon(Icons.credit_card)),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: my parent is Column not scaffold

Comment: Can you include full widget? more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

To move `Row` to the bottom of the screen in `Column` you can use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end` property in Column.

Updated Code:

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
  children: [
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: const [
        SizedBox(
          width: 40,
        ),
        CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          radius: 27,
          child: Icon(Icons.add_call),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 40,
        ),
        CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            radius: 27,
            child: Icon(Icons.mail)),
        SizedBox(
          width: 40,
        ),
        CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            radius: 27,
            child: Icon(Icons.credit_card)),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: it is not working

Comment: it is working if Column is the only child in the screen

Comment: @rnandyala i have added output in my answer

Comment: return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(),
            child: Column(
              children: [ I have this hierarchy  I have two children constrianedBox and column

Comment: @rnandyala remove `SingleChildScrollView` and `ConstrainedBox` from your code

Comment: is there a better way I mean without removing **SingleChildScrollView** and **ConstrainedBox**

Comment: With `SingleChildScrollView` we can't define the height...if we use media queries then we are getting errors I am unable to solve that issue......... you can remove `SingleChildScrollView` to get the expected behaviour

Answer (score 0):

if you want to place the row on the bottom you can't wrap the row with an expanded widget.

but if you want that the row has the width of the screen you can set the width to that:

```
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
```

and if you want place the row to the bottom then you can do that with a flexible sizedBox

```
Column(
  children: [
    ...,
    Flexible(
      child: SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,),
    ),
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: const [
        SizedBox(
          width: 40,
        ),
        CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          radius: 27,
          child: Icon(Icons.add_call),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 40,
        ),
        CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            radius: 27,
            child: Icon(Icons.mail)),
        SizedBox(
          width: 40,
        ),
        CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            radius: 27,
            child: Icon(Icons.credit_card)),
      ],
    ),
  ],
)
```

;

Comment: I am getting error as no mediaquery ancestor found

Comment: do you use MediaQuery inside of a build method?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well,
Wrap `Column` with `Align` and `Align` with `stack`

```
Stack(
     children: <Widget>[
              Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Column()
                    
    ],)
```

Comment: it is not working